# How to remove duplicate data in the UIPickerView in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6, uipickerview

[image: As you can see the picture I've uploaded, the Picker View having the duplicate data]

May I know how to remove the duplicate data which all the data is passing from the Parse database. I just select one column and pass that column data to this picker view.
I've try to find the `query.wherekey` but it didn't have the DISTINCT function which similar to the SQL statement, so what should I do to avoid the data duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you add items one by one into your self.pickerString array, just verify if this array contains or not the new value before addObject new value to the array. For example:

```
if !self.pickerString.contains(object["Intake"] as! String) {
     self.pickerString.append(object["Intake"] as! String)
}
```

There is no built-in function to remove duplicate items in an array in swift (correct me if I'm wrong). However, you can add new features for array with 'extension' keyword:

```
extension Array {
    func distinct<T: Equatable>() -> [T] {
        var newArray = [T]()
        for item in self {
            if !contains(newArray, item as! T) {
                newArray.append(item as! T)
            }
        }
        return newArray
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let s = ["344","333","1","2","333"]
var p = s.distinct() as [String]
```

Comment: ohh thanks @HoaParis, it does help me to remove the duplicate data. Thanks. But I want to ask one more question, I pass the data from the column in the Parse, but how come the data is just partially in the picker view?

Comment: Do you know what problem is the picker view just passing the partially data from that column instead of getting fully data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have anything like distinct on Parse, you'll have to download all rows and then filter out equal values.

For a functional approach:

```
func distinct<T: Equatable>(source: [T]) -> [T] {
  var unique = [T]()
  for item in source {
    if !contains(unique, item) {
      unique.append(item)
    }
  }
  return unique
}

[...]
self.pickerString = distinct(objects)
[...]
```